# How to generate combination with pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a map like this

```
{Tim, [Badminton, Basketball]}
{Viola, [Badminton, Baseball]}
{David, [Basketball]}
....
```

I use pig to find which games can they play together

for example, Tim and Viola can play Badminton together
Tim, Viola, David can not play together

I also need to find what combination can play more than N types of ball games.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward if you change the way you present the data.

At the moment, you have :

```
{Tim, [Badminton, Basketball]}
{Viola, [Badminton, Baseball]}
```

Now, let consider you flat your map games and to have a two-columns dataset :

```
{Tim, Badminton}
{Tim, Basketball}
{Viola, Badminton}
{Viola, Baseball}
```

You group on the second column and you will immediatly have the persons that can to play together.

There is also the possibility to use DataFu Bag's join `BagLeftOuterJoin`. However, on your example, it may not worth it.

Comment: it depends what you want to do afterwards, but yes, that can be an option.

Comment: You means there are another solution with this structure? I think my script does not run fast enough..

Comment: If you consume the group through an UDF, the join is not required, it depends how you exploit that information.